# Removal of YouTube Logo from an application using YouTube API in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube

How to remove the YouTube logo from a simple embedded video using the YouTube API in an app so designed in Android Studio?

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.user.myyoutubeapp">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application


        android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Next"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>`
```

XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/view"
        class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"
        id="@+id/myyoutubeapp"
        layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[I need to hide the marked logo from the embedded video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zkhS.jpg)

What necessary changes can be made in order to remove the YouTube logo from the designed app above.

Comment: Using the embed link, you can use the flag 'modestbranding' to hide youtube logo. Not sure how this applies to Android. Eg: https://www.youtube.com/embed/video-link?modestbranding=1

Comment: How to use the embed link, because in java code file, one only needs to enter the appending string value to the youTubePlayer.loadVideo() command..!! @AnuraagBaishya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is use PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS and the logo will not be visible. 
 **youtubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS)**
But then you will have to make your own implementation for the youtube player controls.

Please let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! Yes this actually worked..!! But what if i want to keep the other controls..? Like as you too mentioned that one needs to implement its own youtube player controls, like how to implement or design the controls ourselves? I would be great if you could help me out with this to..!! Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You can easily manage the play pause functionality on clickevents of your buttons use youtubePlayer.play() and youtubePlayer.pause and implement seekbar and on seekbars progress changed implement yoututbePlayer.seekToMillis((int)(youtubePlayer.getDurationMillis()*progress)/100)

Comment: @VibhorGupta please upvote and Accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: @AmanRawat can we put the play/pause buttons and the seekbar **on the video** (just like YouTube)?